# Get count of mutually shared relations

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have three tables that look like:

```
users:
id

event_registration:
id
user_id
event_id

events:
id
```

A user registers for an event and this registration is recorded in event_registration.

Is there a way I can calculate the count of events that a given set of users mutually share in a single MySQL statement? I figured out how to do this for two users, but I'd like to refactor 
 it to support X number of users (including just one user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select count(event_id) as events
from event_registration
where user_id in (1,2,3)
group by event_id
having count(distinct user_id) = 3
```

You have to adjust the number `3` in the `having` clause acourding to the number of `user_id`s you are using in your `in` clause.